# How to plot PCA loadings vs spectral region

Tags: data-mining, visualization, orange

I am trying to plot the PCA loadings vs spectra. So far I can retrieve the PCA coordinates per observation. In a manual, I saw there was a widget called curves to do this. It does exactly what I need but it seems impossible to find it.

Thank you

[image]